# enable a flutter inspector shortcut along with other debug shortcuts in VSCode

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

[image]

How can we enable and disable the flutter inspector shortcut along with other debug shortcuts in VSCode.

Comment: It opens as a new tab in VSC besides your code tabs 
 https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/devtools/inspector

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [dart. showDevToolsDebugToolBarButtons](https://dartcode.org/docs/settings/#dartshowdevtoolsdebugtoolbarbuttons) setting to control this.

Although if the Inspector button has disappeared in debug mode, you may be seeing a bug (https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/3477). This has recently been fixed but not released - although the fix is in the [latest nightly build](https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/actions/runs/1036619202) that you can install using the **Extensions: Install from VSIX** command in VS Code after downloading and extracting ([see here for more details](https://dartcode.org/docs/installing-a-preview-release/)).